# Matlab Conditional probability from dataset

Tags: matlab, dataset, probability

I have a Matrix `M` of `500x5` and I need to calculate conditional probability. I have discretised my data and then I have this code that currently only works with `3` variables rather than `5` but that's fine for now.

The code below already works out the number of times I get `A=1`, `B=1` and `C=1`, the number of times we get `A=2`, `B=1`, `C=1` etc.

```
data = M;

npatients=size(data,1)

asum=zeros(4,2,2)
prob=zeros(4,2,2)
for patient=1:npatients,
h=data(patient,1)
i=data(patient,2)
j=data(patient,3)
asum(h,i,j)=asum(h,i,j)+1
end
for h=1:4,
for i=1:2,
for j=1:2,
prob(h,i,j)=asum(h,i,j)/npatients
end
end
end
```

So I need code to sum over to get the number of time we get `A=1` and `B=1` (adding over all C) to find:

```
Prob(C=1 given A=1 and B=1) = P(A=1,B=1, C=1)/P( A=1, B=1).
```

This is the rule strength of the first rule. I need to find out how to loop over `A`, `B` and `C` to get the rest and how to actually get this to work in Matlab. I don't know if its of any use but I have code to put each column into its own thing.:

```
dest = M(:,1); gen = M(:,2); age = M(:,3); year = M(:,4); dur = M(:,5);
```

So say `dest` is the consequent and `gen` and `age` are the antecedents how would I do this.

Below is the data of the first `10` patients as an example:

```
destination gender  age
       2    2   2
       2    2   2
       2    2   2
       2    2   2
       2    2   2
       2    1   1
       3    2   2
       2    2   2
       3    2   1
       3    2   1
```

Any help is appreciated and badly needed.

Comment: for `asum(h,i,j)=asum(h,i,j)+1`, `j` is `91` for first patient

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Could you elaborate on it a little please? I have asum(h,i,j)=asum(h,i,j)+1 in the code already (after j=data(patient,3)), but not as a for loop, what should I be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sine your code didn't work by copy & paste, I changed it a little bit,

It's better if you define a function that calculates the probability for given data,

```
function p = prob(data)
n = size(data,1);
uniquedata = unique(data);
p = zeros(length(uniquedata),2);
p(:,2) = uniquedata;
for i = 1 : size(uniquedata,1)
    p(i,1) = sum(data == uniquedata(i)) / n;
end
end
```

Now in another script,

```
data =[3    2   91;
       3    2   86;
       3    2   90;
       3    2   85;
       3    2   86;
       3    1   77;
       4    2   88;
       3    2   90;
       4    2   79;
       4    2   77;
       4    1   65;
       3    1   60];
pdest = prob(data(:,1));
pgend = prob(data(:,2));
page = prob(data(:,3));
```

This will give,

```
page =

0.0833   60.0000
0.0833   65.0000
0.1667   77.0000
0.0833   79.0000
0.0833   85.0000
0.1667   86.0000
0.0833   88.0000
0.1667   90.0000
0.0833   91.0000

pgend =

0.2500    1.0000
0.7500    2.0000

pdest =

0.6667    3.0000
0.3333    4.0000
```

That will give the probabilities you've already calculated,

Note that the second column of `prob` is the valuse and the first column the probability.

When you want to calculate probabilities for `des = 3 & gend = 2` you should create a new data set and call `prob`, for new data set use,

```
mapd2g3 = data(:,1) == 3 & data(:,2) == 2;
datad2g3 = data(mapd2g3,:)

 3     2    91
 3     2    86
 3     2    90
 3     2    85
 3     2    86
 3     2    90

paged2g3 = prob(datad2g3(:,3))

0.1667   85.0000
0.3333   86.0000
0.3333   90.0000
0.1667   91.0000
```

This is the `prob(age|dest = 3 & gend = 2)` .

You could even write a function to create the data sets.

Comment: The reason it wouldn't work by copy and paste is because its not the full code, sorry about that. Also i forgot that to say that the program discretises age into 1 or 2 with 1 = <= 80 and 2 = >80

Comment: @adammcbrinn, see if the probabilities are correct.

Comment: thank you this is really useful, however im not sure how to use functions. Do i create a file called prob and put the first bit in it and then call it, if so how do i call it?

Comment: @adammcbrinn, yes copy the fist script in a new m-file and save it with the name `prob`. and in your main script call it like `pdest = prob(data(:,1));` as I have. And you have to give the right column of data as input to `prob`. It will act like one of matlab's own functions. I noticed you posted the same question yesterday but it was very messy! now it's better.

Comment: Yeah it works :D I was looking at it and thought it didn't look right and then remembered the data was discretised haha. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I've just realised that you have "age|dest = 3 & gend = 2" but since dest is the consequent and age and gen are the antecedents should it not be different. Also one last question, how exactly are the results read so what would 0.2500    1.0000
,0.7500    2.0000 mean?

Comment: @adammcbrinn, It means `p(gend = 1) = 0.25` or `p(gend = 2) = .75`. I didn't fully understand first part of your question (my English is not that good!).

Comment: @adammcbrinn, for example `prob(age=85|dest = 3 & gend = 2) = .1667`